# Exclude hidden characters from SQL comparison

Tags: sql, ms-access, replace

I want to search within a column where some rows has hidden characters. When I use `=` operator there is no result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM result 
WHERE destination = 'x'
```

and when I use like operator the result are more than what I expect in `=` operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM result 
WHERE destination LIKE '%x%'
```

I guess the reason that `=` operator has no result is because I have originally converted an Excel file to a Microsoft Access `.MDB` database file and there are some hidden characters in data columns (I have no idea what are those hidden characters).

How can I exclude all hidden characters from columns when I compare them to x? is there a complete list of hidden characters so I can use `replace` function?

Comment: Probably you have whitespaces at the end or even null-terminator. I suggest to copy from Access to Notepad++ and click "show invisible characters" Then simply `REPLACE(col_name, character, '')`. You could also post here example value that causes problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hidden characters are whitespace, you should be able to use something like

```
Trim(destination) ='x'
```

However what you most certainly *should* do is fix the data so no hidden chars are there, else you would run into all kinds of unexpected problems later on.

Comment: I use built in  import from excel to access. How can I fix inserted data?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour you can do UPDATE statement where you change the data instead of SELECT. For example, UPDATE result SET location=TRIM(location). However, what *exactly* must be done, depends on what kind of wrongness there is with data.